# How to monitor health of Scrapy spiders

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler, monitoring

I have a Scrapy project that parses around 30+ listing sites, and I am trying to figure out a way on how to maintain and monitor the consistency of the scrapers should the underlaying web structure of any of the sites be updated.

There are two ways already that I use to try and achieve this:

1. I have a set of rules that `DropItem` if a few core fields are not present (product title, price, and couple others that are always present). This helps somewhat, but it assumes that if those 3/4 fields are ok then the rest of the structure is ok too. For context, I can't make all other fields required as they by nature are optional (i.e `colour`, `size`, etc)
2. I have unitests that work by running the scrapers on a set of locally saved HTML bodies for each spider. This is good for overall code quality, but does not solve the problem of determining that a spider might be broken because of a DOM change.

There are a few things that I thought of doing along the lines of;

- Potentially calculating an average of how often a field is populated per crawl. If `size` is present on average `30%` of the time, a job that is returning `90%` or `1%` could raise an alert. However I can think of many circumstances where either this would trigger a number of false-positives, or even not trigger a thing and still be broken
- Another thought I had was having a service that somehow monitors the HTML structure, this could be ran before a scrape job and pause if a change is detected. To me this seems like the option that would be the most resilient, but I have no idea how to achieve that.

**TL;DR**

How can I monitor for changes in the structure of a HTML page so that I can avoid running Scrapy jobs that result in corrupted data?

What other options are there to detect that scraping jobs might be corrupted, heuristic or otherwise? `DropItem` already being used wherever possible.

Answer (score 2):

Check [Spidermon](https://github.com/scrapinghub/spidermon)

> Spidermon is an extension for Scrapy spiders. The package provides
>   useful tools for data validation, stats monitoring, and notification
>   messages. This way you leave the monitoring task to Spidermon and just
>   check the reports/notifications.

Comment: thanks, this sounds like it could help with the post-scrape monitoring side of things

Answer (score 2):

I personally monitor my fleet of spiders with [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/). Prometheus is a monitoring solution for numeric data that collects metrics from web services. I.e. your service has to expose the metrics on a HTTP endpoint and Prometheus will collect them from there.

This does not work for Scrapy out-of-the-box, because scrapy spiders will finish after some time. For me it worked, because I developed [a Python project that schedules scrapy spiders](https://www.molescrape.com/) for myself. Other methods are however possible:

- if your spiders run for several minutes Prometheus still recommends to expose the metrics directly on the process that will stop after some time (and fetch it with Prometheus once per minute)
- Prometheus also has a so called *Push Gateway*. Your spiders can send their metrics to this Push Gateway and Prometheus will collect it from there. Caveat: Metrics on the Push Gateway to my knowledge will never expire, i.e. you need some concept to check the freshness of the data or to make sure that freshness of data does not matter (e.g. by using an always increasing counter, which is quite common in Prometheus use cases)

I would recommend the *Push Gateway* approach in most cases, as it can be used with standard scrapy spiders without further effort.

I personally pass these two metrics to Prometheus:

1. Number of times spiders are scheduled
2. Number of items successfully yielded.

I currently cannot monitor things happening inside the spider with Prometheus, because I run my spiders out-of-process, but running scrapy inside an existing Python process is possible (with the Push Gateway approach you will send the data directly from the spider process, so you have access to all data from within your scrapy processes).

### Screenshot

This is a screenshot of my active monitors. Each line in the "Number of Items per Day" chart is one spider and my current trigger is "below 1". I.e. if a spider totally fails I will get an e-mail. Since some spiders might have days without data, I have another trigger "Number of Items per Week".

More refined filters are of course possible if you have more detailed data.

[image: Scrapy Monitoring with Prometheus]

Comment: I also highly recommend prometheus - you can just push all `scrapystats` in a single pipeline and then just play around with your graphs - super easy to integrate with scrapy.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a test-framework for testing crawlers versus live and cached data called [`scrapy-test`](https://gitlab.com/granitosaurus/scrapy-test). The framework is focused on testing parsing and crawling coverage.

You can define tests for fields:

```
from scrapytest.tests import Match, Equal, Type, MoreThan, Map, Len, Required
from myspider.items import PostItem

class TestPost(ItemSpec):
    # defining item that is being covered
    item_cls = PostItem

    # defining field tests
    title_test = Match('.{5,}')
    points_test = Type(int), MoreThan(0)
    author_test = Type(str), Match('.{3}')

    # every item should have title - 100% 
    title_cov = 100
```

As well as stats:

```
class TestStats(StatsSpec):
    # stat pattern: test functions
    validate = { 
        'log_count/ERROR$': LessThan(1),
        'item_scraped_count': MoreThan(1),
        'finish_reason': Match('finished'),
    }
```

So general workflow with `scrapy-test` is to run daily/semi-hourly tests to see to maintain spider health.

Comment: Hey this is awesome, thanks! will take it up for a spin this week.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say size is the 3rd field in an output csv, you can see how many of the last 10 are missing with:

> tail output.csv | cut -f3 -d, | grep -v [0-9] | wc -l

Then you can find something to visualize that on a graph or alert when a condition is met.
[I think this project looks interesting](https://github.com/sqshq/sampler)